# Engine Yard Rails app - Terminating SSL at an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) and passing X-Forwarded-Proto http header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, http-headers, engineyard

Followed the Engine Yard docs at https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21715452-use-elastic-load-balancing-with-engine-yard-cloud

Got this set up and appeared to working well allowing us to use SSL Terminated at the ELB instead at the server. In theory this should allow us to use and multiple SSL certs in a single environment.

This setup means the traffic between the browser and the ELB load balancer is SSL, but the onward traffic from the ELB to the application servers is decrypted. This caused us a problem with our rails 3.2.8 application forcing SSL - it redirects every decrypted request back to it's https equivalent, which sends a decrypted request from the load balancer to the application server again, causing an infinite loop condition.

If we disable the forcing of SSL in our app we need to test each request to see if it came from an SSL connection, if it did we can respond, if not, redirect it.

According to this release note ( http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/7778622769836370 ) the ELB will pass the X-Forwarded-Proto header containing 'https' when traffic is passed from a https connection.

Firstly there is no header called 'X-Forwarded-Proto' in the request on Engine Yard. 'HTTP_X-FORWARDED_PROTO' does exist, but it always contains 'http' even when traffic is sent over SSL to the ELB.

Can anyone offer any insight into this or ideas for a workaround? I've tried EY support without much luck so far.

Comment: If you contact EngineYard, they can enable the stunnel feature flag for your app, which will keep the x-proto-forward in place and not strip it out.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for the X-Forwarded-Port header, which is 443 if the request came to the load balancer over ssl. That would be `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT` in the rack env.

We use [this modified rack-ssl](https://github.com/Kovalo/rack-ssl/blob/x_forwarded_port/lib/rack/ssl.rb#L41) gem in our Engine Yard Rails app as a workaround.

Comment: Typo: `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT`